# /proc/[pid]/fd/[0, 1, 2]: No such file or device - even though file exists

Tags: linux, process, fifo, ipc, unix-sockets

I'm trying to access a process' `stdio` streams from outside its parent process. I've found the `/proc/[pid]/fd` directory, but when I try

```
$ cat /proc/[pid]/fd/1
```

I get a `No such file or device` error. I know for certain that it exists, as Dolphin (file explorer) shows it.

I also happened to notice the file explorer lists it as a *socket* and trying to read from it as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/jadell/871512) produces a similar error. This appeared odd to me as `stdio` streams are typically pipes, rather than sockets, so I'm not sure what's up here.

I'd like to point out also that the processes are started by the same user and attempting to access it with `sudo` didn't work either. I apologise if this question appears noobish, but I'd sincerely appreciate some guidance - perhaps there's a better way of accessing the stdio pipes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr;** As of 2020, you cannot do that (or anything similar) if `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` is a socket.

The stdin, stdout, stderr of a process may be any kind of file, not necessarily pipes, regular files, etc. They can also be sockets.

On Linux, the `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` are a special kind of symbolic links which allow you to open **from the scratch** the actual file a file descriptor refers to, and do it even if the file has been removed, or it didn't ever have any presence in any file system at all (e.g. a file created with `memfd_create(2)`).

But sockets are a notable exception, and they cannot be opened that way (nor is it obvious at all how that could be implemented: would an `open()` on `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` create another connection to the server if that fd is a connected socket? what if the socket is explicitly bound to a local port?).

Recent versions of Linux kernels have introduced a new system call, [`pidfd_getfd(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_getfd.2.html), which allows you to "steal" a file descriptor from another process, in the same way you were able to pass it via Unix sockets, but without the collaboration of the victim process. But that hasn't yet made its way in most Linux distros.

Comment: okay so do I understand this correctly, I cannot access these if they are sockets, however if the process opens stdio as pipes, I would be able to intercept them?

Comment: @JacobSchneider yes, if they're pipes, you can open and read from them, but you will compete with the process also reading from them, so you may get only part of the data.

Comment: And if fd 0 of a process is a pipe, and you're opening the `/proc/<pid>/fd/0` of a process in write-only mode, you will open the other side of the pipe, and you can fake input data to that process.

Comment: understood. You also mentioned a system call `pidfd_getfd(2)` and its presence in modern kernel versions. I should wait until widespread support to use it?

Comment: Yes, that's a [very recent addition](https://lwn.net/Articles/808997/). Until then, you could attach to the process with `ptrace()`, have it open a unix socket, and send the fd(s) via `SCM_RIGHTS`. That's quite involved, and I'm not aware of any tool which does that.

Comment: understood. Thanks for your help. I'll let you know how I go.