# Is it possible to open/load an existing event_fd just like opening files?

Tags: linux

The goal is to use `event_fd` across processes in Python. The issue is that an `event_fd` created in the parent process with a file descriptor, say 10, does not exist in the child process. Or if a file descriptor 10 exists in the child process, it's related to something else.

I tried opening a "file" that points to the event fd in the parent process:

`open("/proc/<parent_process_pid>/fd/<event_fd_in_parent_process>", os.O_RDWR)`

but I get a permission denied. I tried read only but I also got permission denied.

Is there some way to open the "same" `event_fd` just like it is to open the same file given a path?

Comment: No, it's not yet possible. See the discussion [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613450/414777) -- it applies not only to sockets, but also to other "special" fds. If you can modify both programs, you can pass the fd with `SCM_RIGHTS` on a unix domain socket.

Comment: Also see Q5 of the `epoll(7)` manpage.